# SVMc does not plot

Tags: r, svm

Here is my data.
head(data)

```
      Age Education Country Ethnicity  Nscore Escore Oscore  Ascore   Cscore Impulsive     SS Class
    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>
1 -0.952    -0.611   -0.570     0.114  0.0426 -0.806  0.883 -0.302   1.13       -0.217  0.765 1    
2 -0.0785    0.455   -0.570    -0.317 -0.467   0.476  1.44  -0.302  -0.406       0.193  0.765 1    
3 -0.952    -0.611   -0.570    -0.317 -0.348   0.805  1.44   0.590  -0.00665     0.193  1.22  1    
4  1.09     -0.0592   0.961    -0.317  0.0426  0.638 -1.68  -1.08   -0.00665    -0.711 -1.18  0    
5 -0.952    -0.0592  -0.570    -0.317  1.02    0.962  0.293 -1.62   -0.899       0.881  0.401 1    
6 -0.0785   -0.611   -0.285    -0.317  0.911  -0.948  1.24  -0.0173 -0.653      -0.217 -0.846 1
```

I have split the data 70% training and 30% testing and identified the optimal C and gamma and applied SVM for classification.

```
gamma <- seq(0,1, by = 0.005)
cost <- c(0.01,5, by = 0.05)
parms <- expand.grid(cost=cost, gamma=gamma)  
acc_test <- numeric()
accuracy1 <- NULL
accuracy2 <- NULL

# - Identify best combintion of Gamma and Cost for SVM - #

for(i in 1:NROW(parms)){        
  
  learn_svm <- svm(Class~., data=train_data, gamma=parms$gamma[i], cost=parms$cost[i])
  
  pre_svm <- predict(learn_svm, test_data[,-12])
  
  accuracy1 <- confusionMatrix(pre_svm, test_data$Class)
  
  accuracy2[i] <- accuracy1$overall[1]
  
}


acc <- data.frame(p= seq(1,NROW(parms)), cnt = accuracy2)
opt_p <- subset(acc, cnt==max(cnt))[1,] 
sub <- paste("Optimal number of parameter is", opt_p$p, "(accuracy :", opt_p$cnt,") in SVM")     
train.svm <-svm(Class~.,
                    data=train_data,
                    type="C-classification",
                    kernel="radial",
                    scale = TRUE, 
                    cost = 0.01, 
                    gamma = 0.045)

svm.pred <- predict(train.svm, test_data[,-12])

#confusion matrix
health.cat.svm <- confusionMatrix(svm.pred, test_data$Class)
health.cat.svm
```

When I try to plot it, it gives me an error I am not sure why. Is there another way I can plot it?

```
> plot(train.svm, train_data)
Error in plot.svm(train.svm, train_data) : missing formula.
```

Comment: Reading `?plot.svm` suggests that its call should be `plot(x, data, formula, ...)`, and the description of `formula` includes *"Only needed if more than two input variables are used."* I'm inferring that your `train_data` has the same columns as your `data`, so there are clearly more than two columns. You need to either reduce your data to be just two columns, or specify the `formula=` argument.